# usemap attribut in mozilla firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, imagemap

i have this snippet:

`<body>
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="poly" coords="39,195,70,180,33,117,7,77" href="result.php?usa=california" alt="ca">
  <area shape="poly" coords="64,199,81,153,122,160,113,221" href="result.php?usa=arizona" alt="az">
   <area shape="poly" coords="113,221,169,219,175,165,121,159" href="result.php?usa=new mexico" alt="nm">
   <area shape="poly" coords="70,175,89,98,42,88,35,119" href="result.php?usa=nevada" alt="nv">
  <area shape="poly" coords="80,152,123,159,130,116,89,98" href="result.php?usa=utah" alt="ut">
   <area shape="poly" coords="122,159,184,164,186,120,128,114" href="result.php?usa=colorado" alt="co">

   <area shape="poly" coords="31,6,81,17,76,49,23,32" href="result.php?usa=washington" alt="wa">
   <area shape="poly" coords="76,49,23,32,65,91,7,77" href="result.php?usa=oregon" alt="or">
   <area shape="poly" coords="66,92,83,17,118,74,113,101" href="result.php?usa=idaho" alt="id">
  <area shape="poly" coords="104,72,90,18,174,75,177,31" href="result.php?usa=montana" alt="mt">
   <area shape="poly" coords="119,69,112,113,170,118,173,75" href="result.php?usa=wyoming" alt="wy">

   <area shape="poly" coords="178,30,228,34,233,60,175,65" href="result.php?usa=north dakota" alt="nd">
  <area shape="poly" coords="175,65,233,60,231,103,172,98" href="result.php?usa=south dakota" alt="sd">
   <area shape="poly" coords="231,103,172,98,185,131,141,134" href="result.php?usa=nebraska" alt="ne">
   <area shape="poly" coords="185,131,141,134,184,164,249,167" href="result.php?usa=kansas" alt="ks">
  <area shape="poly" coords="201,165,249,167,207,197,250,204" href="result.php?usa=oklahoma" alt="ok">
   <area shape="poly" coords="176,170,259,233,152,245,223,287" href="result.php?usa=texas" alt="tx">

   <area shape="poly" coords="230,36,233,95,275,94,268,41" href="result.php?usa=minnesota" alt="mn">
   <area shape="poly" coords="234,94,275,94,239,127,278,127" href="result.php?usa=iowa" alt="ia">
   <area shape="poly" coords="239,127,278,127,295,170,250,173" href="result.php?usa=missouri" alt="mo">
  <area shape="poly" coords="250,173,251,204,292,177,282,209" href="result.php?usa=arkansas" alt="ar">
   <area shape="poly" coords="255,209,281,210,261,246,298,240" href="result.php?usa=louisiana" alt="la">

   <area shape="poly" coords="269,54,301,72,280,104,302,103" href="result.php?usa=wisconsin" alt="wi">
   <area shape="poly" coords="324,63,346,92,342,107,313,109" href="result.php?usa=michigan" alt="mi">
   <area shape="poly" coords="280,104,302,103,282,143,307,152" href="result.php?usa=illinois" alt="il">
  <area shape="poly" coords="313,109,307,153,329,109,332,139" href="result.php?usa=indiana" alt="in">
   <area shape="poly" coords="329,109,332,139,358,134,362,101" href="result.php?usa=ohio" alt="oh">

    <area shape="poly" coords="332,137,358,153,348,164,302,163" href="result.php?usa=kentucky" alt="ky">
  <area shape="poly" coords="295,171,364,164,343,182,288,188" href="result.php?usa=tennessee" alt="tn">
   <area shape="poly" coords="288,188,308,186,279,234,308,286" href="result.php?usa=mississippi" alt="ms">
   <area shape="poly" coords="309,185,310,235,330,134,340,230" href="result.php?usa=alabama" alt="al">
  <area shape="poly" coords="329,184,352,183,343,230,380,225" href="result.php?usa=georgia" alt="ga">
   <area shape="poly" coords="319,131,374,227,403,279,387,286" href="result.php?usa=florida" alt="fl">

    <area shape="poly" coords="365,126,358,127,372,151,353,144" href="result.php?usa=west virginia" alt="wv">
  <area shape="poly" coords="376,210,395,188,354,184,370,176" href="result.php?usa=south carolina" alt="sc">
   <area shape="poly" coords="405,179,345,179,411,159,364,162" href="result.php?usa=north carolina" alt="nc">
   <area shape="poly" coords="389,125,413,159,372,150,361,163" href="result.php?usa=virginia" alt="va">
  <area shape="poly" coords="367,124,366,100,406,94,410,116" href="result.php?usa=pennsylvania" alt="pa">
   <area shape="poly" coords="438,73,430,38,459,44,440,17" href="result.php?usa=maine" alt="me">
    <area shape="poly" coords="414,56,419,100,405,92,373,90" href="result.php?usa=new york" alt="ny">

     <area shape="poly" coords="426,56,415,55,425,79,418,78" href="result.php?usa=vermont" alt="vt">
  <area shape="poly" coords="429,49,439,73,425,78,428,59" href="result.php?usa=new hampshire" alt="nh">
   <area shape="poly" coords="422,97,419,90,433,86,436,92" href="result.php?usa=connecticut" alt="ct">
   <area shape="poly" coords="418,81,420,89,438,77,441,85" href="result.php?usa=massachusetts" alt="ma">
  <area shape="poly" coords="431,96,412,100,410,117,416,125" href="result.php?usa=new jersey" alt="nj">
   <area shape="poly" coords="406,118,390,124,416,131,412,164" href="result.php?usa=maryland" alt="md">


</map>
<form name="search" method="post"  style="position:relative;left:300px;height:800px; width: 600px;" >
                                                           <div name="map" style="width:1200px; height: 150px;">
                                                           <a name="map"><img src="../images/usa.gif"/ usemap="planetmap"></a>
                                                            </div>`

this code works when i use the browser `google chrome` 
 but when i use `mozilla firefox` the parts of image became inclickable
 i don't know if a code html depends of the type and the version of the browser because it is a simple html code to divide the parts of image and redirect to others pages according to the part clicked 
 so:

- what is the cause of this error ?
- how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slash after your `usemap` attribute. Fix that.

Change

```
<img src="../images/usa.gif"/ usemap="planetmap">
```

To

```
<img src="../images/usa.gif" usemap="#planetmap" />
```

Edit: Also try adding the id attribute to the map.

```
<map name="planetmap" id="planetmap">
```